# Problem with loading images from a javascript file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem using "setInterval" within React. If I don't use "setInterval", there's no problem, but when I use it, my images won't appeear on my page.Please help.

Here is my component where I've imported the JS file containing the images:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './lastricouri.jpg';
import img from './app.js';
import inter from './app.js';


class Logo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id = 'header-container'>
                <img src ={logo} id='tricouri'></img>
                <img src={inter}></img>
                <div id='btns'>
                    <a href='#' id='logi'>Log In</a>
                    <a href='#' id='signup'>Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <input type='text' id='txt' placeholder='Ai libertatea de a alege!'></input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Logo;
```

And here is my component that contains the images:

import first from './1.jpg';

```
import second from './2.jpg';
import third from './3.jpg';
import fourth from './4.jpg';
import fifth from './5.jpg';

let inter = setInterval(() => {
    const tshirts = [first,second,third,fourth,fifth];
        const rndimg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    
        const img = tshirts[rndimg]; 
},3000);
        
export default inter;
```

Comment: The problem is that `setInterval` returns the timer ID (which one may use to cancel the timer later). But your Logo component expects an image, so you probably should rewrite the Logo component and place random image reload logic there

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval returns a unique interval id which is being assigned to the inter variable. inter does not contain your image source. If you want to assign a random image change your code like this

```
let inter;
setInterval(() => {
    const tshirts = [first,second,third,fourth,fifth];
    const rndimg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    inter = tshirts[rndimg]; 
},3000);

export default inter;
```